# Game maker studio Visual bug

Tags: game-maker-studio-1.4

I have an issue where when I use the physics system to have collision between the character and the wall, the Sprite will SOMETIMES vibrate when you hold to move into the wall. As an additional thing as they may be related, if I turn up the player's speed value they're able to glitch through the walls. Right now the collision system I have is really basic, so there isn't much coding but here's related info. 
Wall's density is set to 0 while player is .1
Room has physics enabled but has no set gravity
I have a drag and drop collision event with only a comment in it.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/001_advanced%20use/more%20about%20objects/physics.html
Restitution: In physics, restitution is defined as "the return of an object or system to its original state after elastic deformation", but as the fixtures in the GameMaker: Studio are really rigid bodies and cannot be deformed, restitution is really a way of saying how "bouncy" the fixture is. This setting will affect how much an object "bounces" when it collides with other objects and is co-dependant on other forces that act on the instance like gravity and friction.

That could be ansver to "vibrations". Else you may tru to create code which will check if object is trying to move towards obstacle and stop its movement to prevent built-in physics from causing any problems.

wall skipping: This is usual behavior of built-in game-maker collisions. main problem is that game-maker "teleports" objects "by speed in its direction", which means that when speed is greater than size of any object, game-maker collision system may fail.